# WPF MVVM: Notifying the View of a change to an element within an ObservableCollection?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm

Calling OnPropertyChanged for an ObservableCollection only works when there has been some change to the properties of the collection, not the objects it contains (add, remove, clear, etc).

Is there any way to notify the View that there has been a change to an item within the collection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The objects it contains have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged as well. In your setter you trigger the event, and WPF will pick up on this and read in the new value as long as you are using two-way bindings or read-only bindings.